# C# Print file Without saving as PDF

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to print a simple receipt (text file), but when I do so my PC asks me to save the file (as PDF). Here is my code:

```
    private void btn_Pay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //Button "Pay" clicked

        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Print receipt?", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes) {
            //Print receipt

            ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"print.txt");
            psi.Verb = "PRINT";

            try {
                Process.Start(psi);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't want to save my text file (print.txt) as a pdf file I just want to print the text file. (I don't have an actual printer connected to my computer, nor network, so I can't really print it, I just want to test it - not sure if that's an issue or not. The printer icon appeared in the bottom-right corner of my screen when I tried.)

Is there a way to get rid of the whole "save file (as pdf)"-process?

Comment: It seems that you have installed a PDF printer driver as default printer. (Foxit, Adobe, the list is long)

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly telling to use `ShellExecute`?

Comment: No, dcg. I have not. I don't know what it is, what it does or how to do it. All I've tried so far can be seen above.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a printer the default function of windows is "Print to PDF"..[The screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46OgN.png)

I think it is why it saves pdf.
Try to connect the printer and set it as primary.

Comment: I see. Problem is I don't have a printer, so I can't try it. Do you reckon the code above would work if I had a printer?